# Filter chain with spring-security and webflux public patterns

Tags: spring, security, spring-webflux

I might be missing something obvious, but can't figure it out myself. So I hope you will be able to help me.

I am trying to secure a spring webflux app, well in fact just a subset of the app and I want some endpoints not to be secured. So here is my security config:

```
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig  {

    ...

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/process_login", "/login", "/logout").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/api/team").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
                .addFilterAt(webFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION)
                .addFilterAt(new AuthorizationModifierFilter(),SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            ;
        http.httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
    ...
}
```

When accessing the /api/team endpoint I was expecting not to pass the security filter chain but I am passing into my security filters.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't break the chain. It should be something like this. try this, if it doesn't work I will update accordingly

```
private static String[] permittedUrl = new String[]{
    "/process_login", "/login", "/logout", "/api/team"
};
........
........
return http
         .csrf().disable()
         .cors().disable()
         .formLogin().disable()
         .httpBasic().disable()
         .exceptionHandling()
         .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) ->
                 Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                     swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                 })
         )
         .accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) ->
                 Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                     swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                 })
         )
         .and()
         .authorizeExchange()
         .pathMatchers(permittedUrl).permitAll()
         .anyExchange()
         .authenticated()
         .and()
         .build();
```

Comment: Hi Shoshi
Your solution helped me to figure out I was looking in the wrong direction.
You are right breaking the chain seems not ideal, your approach helped me to identify I was injecting manually my own ServerWebExchangeMatcher into the security chain but as I declared it as a bean, I think Spring is injecting it in all chains. So I need some time to review my full configuration.
I'll come back soon with updated info; either my working conf or alternate question :)

Comment: That's great. Hope you will find a solution. Let me know.

Comment: ok got it working. the webfilter I am injecting is always invoked (whether or not the request was in the permitAll() list). So I have injected this list into my webFilter and used a NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher as authenticationMatcher. Now it works as expected.